# How to create expression with type cast for automapper to create map for Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper, automapper-3

I am having two classes :

source.Employee and destination.Employee .

I am getting just two name in my function destination property name i.e destination.TestEnum1 and source property name i.e source.TestEnum1.

I want to create expression dynamically as i mentioned below.

```
 var mapExpr = Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.Employee, destination.Employee>().ForMember(destination => destination.TestEnum1, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (destination.MyEnum2)source.TestEnum1));
```

The expression is just

```
destination => destination.TestEnum1, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (destination.MyEnum2)source.TestEnum1)
```

I am creating it to map Enum in Project().To();.
As

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.MyEnum1, destination.MyEnum2>()
```

gives exception unable to map MyEnum2 to int 32.

Source employee :

```
namespace Soure
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Department dept1 { get; set; }

        public int age { get; set; }

        public MyEnum1 TestEnum1 { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MyEnum1
    {
        red = 1,
        yellow = 2
    }
}
```

destination employee class :

```
namespace destination
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int age { get; set; }
        public MyEnum2 TestEnum1 { get; set; }

        public Departments dept1 { get; set; }

    }
    public enum MyEnum2
    {
        red = 1,
        yellow = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I had added both part. The actual i want i.e create map. But even i get something to create expression still i can manage to create map.

Comment: You could create a Custom Value Resolver to dynamically map between different enums based on their integer values. https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers

Comment: @Dietz ValueResolver is not supported in Queryable Extension

Answer (score 0):

You might think of using `Custom Type Converters` for this, found [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters).

Here I made a sample application for you (simplified a bit) where I implemented a `Enum1to2TypeConverter` inheriting from the generic interface `ITypeConverter`:

```
public class Employee1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyEnum1 TestEnum { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum1
{
    red = 1,
    yellow = 2
}

public class Employee2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyEnum2 TestEnum { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum2
{
    red = 1,
    yellow = 2
}

public class Enum1to2TypeConverter : ITypeConverter<MyEnum1, MyEnum2>
{
    public MyEnum2 Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return (MyEnum2)(context.SourceValue);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Example()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum1, MyEnum2>().ConvertUsing(new Enum1to2TypeConverter());
        Mapper.CreateMap<Employee1, Employee2>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var source = new Employee1
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Employee1-Name",
            TestEnum = MyEnum1.yellow
        };

        Employee2 result = Mapper.Map<Employee1, Employee2>(source);
        //Check content of result here!
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (new Test()).Example();
    }
}
```

Comment: your code works in Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Soure.Employee>, IEnumerable<destination.Employee>>(empList);    When i map queryable empList.Project().To<destination.Employee>();  it don't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854324/how-to-create-map-for-enum-in-iqueryable-mapping-in-auto-mapper-without-using-fo

Comment: I had given detail example there. Please check it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try this? empList.ToList().Project().To<destination.Employee>();

Comment: it is equivalent to Enumerable. My last goal is return Queryable.

Comment: Then cast the enumerable result to Queryable in the end? But seriously, why exactly do you want to do that, I mean the queryable result?

Comment: see i am using it for NHibernet. So if it is Enumerable then there will be more database hit. IQueryable will reduce the database hit.

Comment: Database hit? You're supposed to have your source objects already available in your memory. So you must be done with the database before AutoMapper maps your objects of a type to another.

Comment: i didn't give the exact method. I had given the sample app. That i can implement in application. Yes i had create map for main class. As the class contain enumerable then their is problem. So i tried to create separate map for it. My enum contain are same but different enum

Answer (score 0):

As the `enums` in your example share the same underlying `int` types, automapper will handle this automatically as follows:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MyEnum2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyEnum1))    
    ;

    var source = new Foo { MyEnum1 = MyEnum1.yellow };

    var destination = Mapper.Map<Bar>(source);

    Console.WriteLine(destination.MyEnum2);
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qn6a50)**

Answer (score 0):

You can check out ConvertProjectionUsing, which is the ConvertUsing for LINQ.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum1, MyEnum2>().ProjectUsing(src => ???);
```

What should you put inside that ???, I'm not sure, it will depend on your query provider. EF may or may not be able to take that projection and convert it to SQL. You might be able to cast the source to int:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum1, MyEnum2>().ProjectUsing(src => (MyEnum2)(int)src);
```

That is completely dependent on your query provider, though.

Comment: Actually my method is generic which takes private MappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> CreateMap<TSource,TDestination>(){ Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()}  That's why i need to create some method for casting. I can't use ProjectUsing(src => (MyEnum)(int)src)

Comment: I don't see why not - CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>().ProjectUsing(src => (TDestination)(int)src);

Comment: As i say its a generic method. If i get string in TDestination. Then it will give me an  exception. I know it will work. But for that i have to handle enum case separately. And that i my last option. I am expecting to make one generic function which will handle everything.

Comment: Your solution always gives me default value to destination enum

Comment: I would focus on getting it to work for *one* enum, not all first. And the way I typically handle this is remove AutoMapper and try to do a manual projection (using Select) until I can find the solution. What LINQ provider are you using, EF?